# In R cannot use AdjustedSharpeRatio() from 'Performance Analytics'

Tags: r

I have some troubles using the function `AdjustedSharpeRatio()` from the package `PerformanceAnalytics`, the following code sample in R 3.0.0:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
logrets = array(dim=c(3,2),c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
weights = c(0.4,0.6)
AdjustedSharpeRatio(rowSums(weights*logrets),0.01)
```

gives the following error:

```
Error in checkData(R) : 
  The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in 
names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, 
columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as 
'1985-03-15'.
```

Replacing the last line with zoo gives the same error:

```
AdjustedSharpeRatio(zoo(rowSums(weights*logrets)),0.01)
```

Am I missing something obvious ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
a <- rowSums(weights*logrets)
names(a) <- c('1985-03-15', '1985-03-16', '1985-03-17')
AdjustedSharpeRatio(a,0.01)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm...not too sure what you are trying to achieve with the `logrets` and `weights` objects there....but if logrets are already in percentages. then maybe something like this...

```
AdjustedSharpeRatio(xts(rowSums(weights*logrets)/100,Sys.Date()-(c(3:1)*365)), Rf=0.01)
```

Comment: `logrets` were log returns of assets ordered by columns and weights are the weights on each assets of your portfolio (the example is putting random values in the logrets)